# jquery .show() .hide() puzzle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a simple jquery animation to show/hide a block of stuff when the title is clicked. 
The markup looks like this:

```
<section class="infoblock off">
<h2><span class="sectiontitle rounded-right">TITLE (click to show/hide)</span></h2>
<div class="info"></div><!--info-->
</section>
```

My javascript looks like this:

```
        $(".infoblock h2").click( function(event) {
        //console.log('show info');

        if ( $(this).parent( $('.infoblock') ).hasClass('off') ) {          
            $(this).parent( $('.infoblock') ).removeClass('off');
            $(this).parent( $('.infoblock') ).addClass('on').children( $('.info') ).show(300);
            console.log( 'On function. Parent class= '+$(this).parent( $('.infoblock') ).attr('class') );

        } else if ( $(this).parent( $('.infoblock') ).hasClass('on') ) {
            $(this).parent( $('.infoblock') ).removeClass('on');
            $(this).parent( $('.infoblock') ).addClass('off');
            $(this).parent( $('.infoblock') ).children( $('.info') ).hide(300);
            console.log( 'Off function. Parent class= '+$(this).parent( $('.infoblock') ).attr('class') );
        }

    });
```

This works **BUT** when I click the title the second time to hide the `.info <div>` the  title gets hidden as well. WHY?!

Comment: It will be better if you can put your demo in jsfiddle.net .

Comment: Emerson, you are specifying a jQuery object in your parent() and children() calls, rather than a selector (which should just be a string). It is not completely clear to me how these methods will behave in this case, but I suspect that is the root of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/RQ2Cw/1/

instead of `parent` use `closest`, and instead of`children` use `find`

```
$(".infoblock h2").click(function(event) {
    //console.log('show info');
    if ($(this).closest('.infoblock').hasClass('off')) {
        $(this).closest('.infoblock').removeClass('off');
        $(this).closest('.infoblock').addClass('on').find('.info').show(300);
        console.log('On function. Parent class= ' + $(this).closest('.infoblock').attr('class'));

    } else if ($(this).parent('.infoblock').hasClass('on')) {
        $(this).closest('.infoblock').removeClass('on');
        $(this).closest('.infoblock').addClass('off');
        $(this).closest('.infoblock').find('.info').hide(300);
        console.log('Off function. Parent class= ' + $(this).closest('.infoblock').attr('class'));
    }

});​
```

or :

```
$(".infoblock h2").click(function(event) {
    var _parent = $(this).closest('.infoblock');
    if (_parent.hasClass('off')) {
        _parent.removeClass('off').addClass('on').find('.info').show(300);

    } else if (_parent.hasClass('on')) {
        _parent.removeClass('on').addClass('off').find('.info').hide(300);
    }

});​
```

Comment: It works. I'm still not quite clear why my original code wasn't working? My selectors seemed to be targeting the right elements, but I guess not.

Comment: There is no reason to perform `$(this).closest('.infoblock')` three or even four times, when that thing can be cached and chained.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused about how to specify selectors. For example, where you have

```
$(this).parent( $('.infoblock') ).hasClass('off')
```

I think you want

```
$(this).parent('.infoblock').hasClass('off')
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cordesmj/5yt6V/) is a working example

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the 'info' class anywhere else, you could use it directly as a selector:

```
$('.info').show(300)
$('.info').hide(300)
```

If you do use the class somewhere else, you could give it an ID `<div id="info" class="info"></div>` and select it using `$('#info')`

Also, if the condition only purpose  is to switch between `hide()` and `show()` (if there is no css associated with the classes), try using the `toggle()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Store a reference to the parent element and make use of jQuery's function chaining, like this:

```
$(".infoblock h2").click( function(event) {
        //console.log('show info');
        var $parent = $(this).parent('.infoblock');

        $parent.toggleClass("off").toggleClass("on").children($('.info')).toggle(300);

        if ($parent.hasClass('on')) {          
            console.log( 'On function. Parent class= '+$parent.attr('class'));
        } else if ($parent.hasClass('off')) {
            console.log( 'Off function. Parent class= '+$parent.attr('class'));
        }
});
```

Comment: This could be simplified by removing the entire `if` block and adding `$parent.children($('.info')).toggle(300);` since the `$parent` classes are toggled anyway

Comment: Ooh, nice. However, the `if` block must remain because of the `console.log()` calls.

Comment: Indeed, but it could always call: `console.log( 'Parent class= '+$parent.attr('class'));` since the class already contains either "on" or "off", it doesn't really need "On function" or "Off function".

Plus, the console.log is probably just for debugging.

Comment: Mm, but then we wouldn't get the "on function" || "off function" the OP wanted. I'm sure there's a better solution though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two lines:

```
$( '.infoblock' ).on( 'click', 'h2', function () {   
    var $elem = $( this ).closest( '.infoblock' ).toggleClass( 'on off' );   
    $elem.find( '.info' )[ $elem.hasClass( 'on' ) ? 'show' : 'hide' ]( 300 );
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/dpdvg/1/

Comment: You can do this in 1 line XD: `$( this ).closest( '.infoblock' ).toggleClass( 'on off' ).children($('.info')).toggle(300);`

Comment: @DangerMonkey Yes, indeed. However, that would assume that the class and display states are synchronized, which might not be the case. (For instance, initially the class `'off'` might be set, and the info-element might be visible (for some reason).

Comment: You are right, this solution would be dependant on the initial state. However, as long as the initial state is coherent, this would be the shortest solution.